# Mount disk 100% full after clean install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04

After struggling for a bit installing Ubuntu I managed to do it by setting the acpi flag to off with the following setup in the installer:

[image]

I have my main Windows 10 running on an NVMe drive and Ubuntu is installed on a SSD.

After a successful installation, it seems that the disk is ENTIRELY full:

[image]

What's going on here? Thanks in advance for any help.

---

**Update**:

I re-installed the system and right away the usage was something like 17%. A few *minutes* later it was up to 70%, seconds later to 71%, etc. How do can I diagnose what's happening?

Comment: Why did you have to set acpi=off? To check what might be happening, in `terminal`, `cd /var/log`, then `ls -alt` and note which log file has the current update time (at the top of the list), it's probably syslog. Then do `more syslog` and see if you can see what's filling up the syslog file. There's your clue.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126485/how-to-disable-a-particular-log-message-from-being-saved-to-var-log/1126514#1126514 for your answer.