# How to disable a particular log message from being saved to var/log?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, log, logging

I'm making a second attempt at resolving [this issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122119/mount-disk-100-full-after-clean-install)

Every time I'd shut the PC off, this error would print what looked like millions of times per second, so I'm almost positive this is the culprit that's filling up the logs:

[image]

`PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, ...`

This is likely because of my particular hardware configuration and the NVMe disk.

Now the question is: How do I prevent this from being logged/saved? Is there a way to disable all system logging?

Updated:

I wasn't able to copy-paste directly but of note are:

`kernel: [    13.202795] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3 AER: Corrected error received: 0000:00:1c3`
which corresponds to in the output of the second command:
`+-1c.3-[08]----00.0 Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me the output (use copy/paste, not screenshot, please) of `grep AER /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lspci -tv`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I wasn't able to copy paste but the log output is just endless lines starting with `kernel` which I've transcribed for you. It looks like... it's the wireless card??

Comment: @heynnema I removed the card last night to confirm that was the issue. I'll put the card back in and update after work re: grub.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: grub fix worked :)

Comment: When you removed the wireless card, did the errors go away? And after re-inserting the card, did the errors return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We looked at two commands... `grep AER /var/log/syslog*` and `sudo lspci -tv`, and determined that your wireless card may have a problem.

Assuming that your wireless card works normally under Windows/Ubuntu, we won't worry too much about it. If it does not work properly, it may be defective, or may need reseating on the motherboard, or it might have a driver issue.

If you added a driver for your wireless card (RTL8192EE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter), it's probably a dkms driver, so check its version number, and status with:

`dkms status` # check driver status

The AER (Advanced Error Reporting) errors that are bombing your `/var/log/syslog`, can be eliminated by:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` # edit this file

**Find:**

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

**Change it to:**

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=noaer"`

**Then:**

`sudo update-grub` # update GRUB

`reboot` # reboot the computer